# C#: Why doesn't Initialize work with a Byte-Array?

Tags: c#

I declare a Byte-Array like this:

```
Byte[] b = new Byte[10];
```

and assign some values:

```
for (int i=0; i<b.Length; i++)
{
    b[i] = 1;
}
```

Now I want to zero the array again and call:

```
b.Initialize();
```

which doesn't work. The array remains unchanged. Isn't b a value-type array?

Comment: Array.Clear is probably what you're looking for

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.initialize.aspx):

> **Caution**
>
> You can use this method only on value types that have constructors; however, value types that are native to C# do not have constructors.

`byte` is native.

Comment: Perhaps most telling from the MSDN article: "This method is designed to help compilers support value-type arrays; most users do not need this method."

Comment: @Marc: Right, I didn't read the caution note in MSDN carefully enough.

Comment: @Ramhound no, it will do no such thing. That creates a new array ; it resets nothing except for the variable. It absolutely does not reinitialize the array.

Comment: Is the method intended for use with languages that allow value types to have *non-trivial* default constructors?